# Can I configure Thunderbird/Enigmail to use encryption only for sending/receiving, not for local storage?

Tags: email, encryption, thunderbird

I'd like to use email encryption only for the transport, not for local storage (for reasoning, see the end). I want to have all my email decrypted locally (in Sent, Deleted, Inbox, etc.), but encrypted when being sent/received.

Reading section "What are the consequences of using e2ee" here
[Introduction to End-to-end encryption in Thunderbird](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/introduction-to-e2e-encryption), they say "the messages in your sent folder will be encrypted", with no hint otherwise.

1. Am I asking for something silly (see below why I want this)?
2. How would this be possible, if it isn't silly? I've tried years ago with Enigmail, but the rules for decoding-on-receive did not work reliably/were not powerful enough to achieve this.

The reason being that my entire local data lives on a Veracrypt volume which is already encrypted, and I'm not paranoid enough to juggle multiple passwords for my data. One should be enough. Searching message texts is a useful feature too, which only works on decryted emails.

Comment: What you want is not possible. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/introduction-to-e2e-encryption

Comment: That's the link I cited as well. But does that also mean it's a silly idea? Why?

Comment: That's a question for the developers

Answer (score 0):

It is very common nowadays that mail clients use IMAP servers, which means that your emails are on the server. The locally stored emails are just a cache copy of the original one on the server. Therefore, it makes a lot of sense *not* to store emails unencrypted.

Hence, email is encrypted for both the recipient(s), as well as the sender.

A good email client should be able to transparently decrypt encrypted emails, and also allow to search search emails. I don't know, however, if Thunderbird supports that.

Comment: I do know, and I don't care about the cached messages. But Thunderbird offers "Local Folders", which are only on my encryted volume and the place where I store messages I want to keep - unencrypted, because they already are on an encrypted volume.

Comment: So while in your scenario, it may be acceptable to keep the local copy of the emails unencrypted, it is still not part of the concept, and I do not know any email client that would support your requirement.